# CSS Media query problem: element shouldn't be affected by media query

Tags: html, css

I'm a totally newbie of html and css, that's probably be a dumb question. Anyway, I wrote this HTML code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'sans serif';
  font-weight: 500;
  color: hsl(224, 23%, 55%);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'sans serif';
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: hsl(245, 75%, 52%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 6%;
  align-self: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: hsl(223, 47%, 23%);
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'sans serif';
  text-decoration-style: underline;
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/pattern-background-desktop.svg);
  background-position-y: -270px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: hsl(225, 100%, 94%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 23%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.illustration-hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-image: url(images/illustration-hero.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  /* margin-bottom:210px; */
}

@media screen and (max-width:377px) {
  body {
    background-image: url(images/pattern-background-mobile.svg);
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.order {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'sans serif';
  color: hsl(223, 47%, 23%);
  font-style: bold;
  align-self: center;
}

.info {
  min-height: 15%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* border:1px solid black; */
  background-color: hsl(225, 100%, 98%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.info img {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.plan {
  height: 100%;
}

.plan ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'sans serif';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.price {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', 'sans serif';
  font-weight: 500;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 67%);
}

.change {
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="illustration-hero"></div>
  <div class="order">Order Summary</div>
  <p>You can now listen to milions of songs,<br> audiobooks and podcast on any device <br> anywhere you like!
  </p>

  <div class="info">
    <img class="icon-music" src="images/icon-music.svg" alt="Icon Music">
    <div class="plan">
      <ul>
        <li>Annual Plan</li>
        <li></li>
        <span class="price">$59.99/year</span>
      </ul>
      <div class="change">
        <a href="#">Change</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="button">Proceed to Payment</button>
```

The problem is the following: in responsive dimension width:1440px it's all perfect fine. In a Iphone-X dimension for example (width:375px) the element marked as .illustration-hero (the blue rectangular image) doesn't have border radius nether flex-start.

I tried to add in the media query .illustration-hero with the same attributes as in the desktop version, without any results.

The fact is that: why do .illustration-hero has not border-radius (nether flex-start) in the IPhone-X version?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I've combined your code into a snippet demo so we can see what you're talking about. The HTML seems incomplete. Please revise as needed. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, I'll explain better my dubt.

Comment: I looked at the code presented here at 375px width and it showed the top border radius at 25px. The `justify-content: flex-start` had no effect because the element *has no content*, and the `background-*` properties had no effect because the URL given doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to understand what are you asking. According to going through your code what I understood is.

1. Media query has no border radius value written init so border radius shouldn't apply init ?
2. you tried to copy paste border radius values in media query and it's not affecting ?

Let me know if I'm understanding correctly.

1. you are writing media query in top bottom approach ie. you are writing css for Big screen and than for small devices so in you case you are giving border radius in Top ie. desktop which will auto apply to small devices.
   if you don't want this to happen than you need to change approach to bottom top.
2. Border radius is not showing because your image size is contain and height is parent div is smaller than width so image never covers the whole width and you don't see border radius

I'll write example for you in top bottom approach just to give you idea.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 23%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.illustration-hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:377px) {
  body {
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300/ff0000');
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .illustration-hero { 
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="illustration-hero"></div>
```

Comment: I tried to explain better the dubt, thank you in every case!

Comment: Now I read your edited question again so I understood the issue. The issue is simple you have given border-size: contain so as your height and width is not in pixel but as per window height and width / percent it becomes so small that the contained image never reaches the end of the width so border radius is still there but it's not visible because image never reaches to corners. Am I understanding correct ?

Comment: I changed with background-size:cover and now it's better. I'm very glad to you :]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question... you are asking that why styles are applying under the media max-width... if that is your question, then the answer is media query doesn't remove all the previous styling but overwrites the specified properties, which means that If you want to overwrite a style through media query, you will have to specify those properties inside media block.
.
If this is not what you have asked, Try rephrasing your question.

Comment: I tried to explain better the concept, posting the full code. Thank you anyway

Comment: Actually it is not overwriting the `.illustration-hero` class, it is just using its previous value specified.
for `.plan` div i suggest you to use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to avoid overflowing

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to fix .plan class in that way. About .illustration-hero , its previous value consists of border-top-left-radius:25px. Same thing for right border. So, in my mind it should be kept also in the IPhone-X dimension. But actually I don't understand why it doesn't appear this rule visually. Same dubt for the rule justify-content:flex-start;

Comment: It would be helpful if you share some screenshots of your problem because the issue is not occurring in my device, and i don't think other repliers are able to see the same problem in their devices...

try doing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R` to clear cache

Comment: https://ibb.co/ngCQXYR that's the IPhone-X version
https://ibb.co/K0MDJHV that's the responsive one